# Magento2 : How to add a new product custom option type?

Tags: magento2, custom-options, xml

Two years ago, I developed under Magento 1.9 a module aiming at adding a new product custom option input type using this tutorial :

http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/custom-input-types-custom-options

I would like now to do the same under Magento 2.1, but as I am just starting developing under Magento 2, I did not manage...

I saw the method to add a product type was to write a product_types.xml file declaring the new type. Is it possible to do the same way, i.e. creating a product_option_types.xml or something like?

Could you please help me on this custom option input type xml declaration?

Thanks for your help,

EDIT :

I started the module using other module examples :

Mine/Custoptiontype/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mine_Custoptiontype" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Mine/Custoptiontype/etc/product_types.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_options.xsd">
    <option name="xfile" label="X File" renderer="Mine\Custoptiontype\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Type\Xfile">
        <inputType name="xfile" label="X File" />
    </option>
</config>
```

Mine\Custoptiontype\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Type\Xfile.php

```
<?php
namespace Mine\Custoptiontype\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Type;

class Xfile extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Type\AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'catalog/product/edit/options/type/xfile.phtml';
}
```

I then installed the module.
My new option type is present in the backend under product, but when I select it, the file.phtml is not displayed...

Comment: I am working on something like that right now. How is your progress on that? Were you able to get it to work as you wanted?

Comment: Yes, I finished this module

Comment: I'm also in need of this, recreating a module I made in 1.7. Could you point us in the right direction of how you got it working?

Comment: Can please post your solution here? I really need this functionality.

Comment: No Problem, I will help you with that, but it is quite big.... will prepare something ASAP

Comment: Thanks Alexglvr, it was very helpful. I will try to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way to the solution :

**1. Create the module**

**2. Declare your new product option : app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/product_options.xml**

**3. Add the new custom Option in Admin/Product :**

- Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Type\Newtype.php
- Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option.php
  to define the template
- create the associated .phtml files

Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/options/type/newtype.phtml

and

Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/options/option.phtml

**4. Add the new custom Option in Frontend Catalog :**

- Vendor\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Options\Type\Newtype.php;
- The associated template : Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/options/type/newtype.phtml
- The layout definition : Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

**5. the Models for all that**

- Vendor\Module\Model\Catalog\Product\Option\Type\Newtype.php
- Vendor\Module\Model\Catalog\Product\Option.php
- Vendor\Module\Model\Catalog\ResourceModel\Product\Option.php

**6. Extend Ui :**

- Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Catalog\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions.php

Hope this help !

Comment: Thanks, Alex! Hopefully following this procedure will get it working, I feel like I've been close but something is missing.

Comment: Okay, I'm a bit stuck as to what I put in

  `Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option.php`
  `Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Catalog\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions.php`

I can't see how they fit in with the rest of the files. Any advice?

Comment: Okay, so 6 hours later and I have the custom option displaying in the add to cart form as expected. But I can't add the product to the cart, getting an error: “The option type to get group instance is incorrect”. I'm pretty sure it's because I'm missing something in one of the model classes. Any advice?

Comment: if it is a file like type custom option that you are creating, you need to extend also Controller/Sales/Download/DownloadCustomOption.php to add you type : if (!$productOption || !$productOption->getId() || ($productOption->getType() != 'file' && $productOption->getType() != 'YOUR_TYPE_ID')) {
            return $resultForward->forward('noroute');
        }

Comment: It's basically a couple of text fields that, when populated, fill in a hidden field which is then submitted as the input. I think I'm close, but just can't work out what I should be adding in an extended class...

Comment: This answer could highly benefit if you put the actual code that needs to into these classes. I tried to follow this and managed to get the option in my admin. But now on frontend I'm hitting all sorts of errors.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/181639/42007