# Magento 2: How to add extenstion attributes for the ProductCustomOptionValuesInterface

Tags: product, custom-options, rest-api, magento2.3.1

I need to add product custom added `Customizable Options` to the product Rest API. I have set that custom options to the below core Interface `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionValuesInterface` and Model `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value` file and options in getting in product API.

But can't override interface so how to add as extension attributes or other override solution for below core dependency.

`Core dependency file path: magento231\vendor\magento\module-catalog\etc\di.xml`

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionValuesInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value" />
```

I have find the issue from github. Can't able to add extenstion attributes for `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionValuesInterface`

**Github Issue link:**
https://github.com/magento/community-features/issues/30

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you show what you have added in those files? and what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have added Mageworxs product custom option like ColorCode, Images and Dependancy etc...

Comment: you can override `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value` class instead of interface or try plugin instead of override class

Comment: I tried to override `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value` class but not worked solution.