# How to add custom option type in Customizable Options

Tags: magento2, custom-options, customizable-options

How can i add custom option type in customizable options? Is there any free extension which added this option?
I followed [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181639/how-to-add-a-new-customizable-product-option) but i can not make it works....

Comment: I would suggest please try this link
https://devhooks.in/blog/magento2-how-to-add-custom-input-type-in-custom-option
https://webkul.com/blog/add-custom-product-option-type-magento-2/

Comment: it does not work.
"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options.php on line 221"